# Check if branches exist or not

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, multivalued-functions, branch-points

We have four multivalued functions:
$f\left( z\right) =\left( \dfrac {z-1}{z+1}\right) ^{\dfrac {1}{2}}$ $g\left( z\right) =\left( \dfrac {z-1}{z+1}\right) ^{\dfrac {1}{3}}$ $h\left( z\right) =\left( z^{2}-1\right) ^{\dfrac {1}{2}}$ $k\left( z\right) =\left( z^{2}-1\right) ^{\dfrac {1}{3}}$

a) Show that one can define branches to all four functions in $\Omega =C\backslash [-1,+\infty [$

b) Show that branches exist for f, g and h but not for k in $\Omega =C\backslash [-1,1 ]$

Comment: Could you perhaps say something about what tools you have, what you know about branch cuts (particularly, do you understand how to construct branches of the square and cube roots?), and where you're stuck?

Comment: I started by rewriting the functions using z=x+iy, then I wrote them on the form e^1/2logz (just an example if the function would be z^1/2). I checked for what values of x and y the absolute value of the function equaled 0 (because then we would get ln0) and for both h(z) and k(z) I got x=1 or x=-1 and y=0. This is where I get stuck. I can't see why k(z) doesn't have a branch in C\[-1,1].

Comment: I meant to write "in C\[-1,1]".

Comment: There's supposed to be a backslash after C but apparently it disappears when I post the comment!

Comment: Let's back up: Are you comfortable with the standard branches of the square and cube root (each real and positive on the positive real axis, and defined on the plane with the non-positive real axis removed)? If so, next ask yourself where the functions $z \mapsto (z - 1)/(z + 1)$ and $z \mapsto z^{2} - 1 = (z - 1)(z + 1)$ hit the non-positive real axis.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang For both z-1/z+1 and z^2-1 I get that they hit the non-positive real axis when z=[-1,1] but I still don't understand how to implement this into the square root and cube root problem. Any further hints?

Comment: A more apt suggestion (on my part) would have been to ask what the image of each mapping is when restricted to the complement of $[-1, \infty)$ or $[-1, 1]$. If you can construct a branch of square root or cube root on the image of $z \mapsto (z - 1)/(z + 1)$ (or on the image of $z \mapsto z^{2} - 1$), then you've constructed a branch of square or cube root on the indicated set. You might also (or instead) consider branches of square root (or cube root) of $z \mapsto z \pm 1$, and see if you can multiply or divide such branches to get the desired functions.